# Why is the root folder empty?

Tags: root

I accessed the root folder by using `sudo chmod 777 /root` command and I seen this folder is empty. I want to know why is the root folder empty?

Comment: That was a terrible idea and you should probably set that back to `750`.

Comment: `/root` is probably the root user's home directory, it may be empty. What we call "root directory" is `/`, this one should not be empty.

Comment: It's probably not empty.  Try this:  ls -la /root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the same reason any other user account that gets rarely used is empty: You didn't put anything in it.

Aside from (possibly) a few config files that start with a `.` and get obscured from a standard `ls` there's no major reason to have much of anything in `/root`.